# ViewModel update - changing properties before saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

After trying around the whole day with model bindings, without results, i decided to ask here.

I have got an asp.net razor view where a user (aka Seller) can edit his user details. Furthermore the user should be able to change his password.

I made a ViewModel:

```
public class EditSellerViewModel
{
    public Seller Seller { get; set; }
    public ChangePasswordModel ChangePasswordModel { get; set; }
}
```

My view has two forms which result in two "Submit" buttons. In my action i check which button was clicked. If the "Passwords" form has been submitted, i want to set the new Password in the Seller entity (that actually works) and SaveChanges() which does not change anything in the database (and does not throw any exception). It simply does nothing.

Furthermore if the "Seller Detail" form was submitted, i want to save the sellers data. But TryUpdateModel is always false, even if i use the second parameter which enables the prefix for ViewModels.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUser(string btnSubmit, FormCollection formValues, EditSellerViewModel editSellerViewModel)
    {
        int uid = baseFunc.GetIdForUsername(User.Identity.Name);
        var seller = bmDBCont.SellerSet.Single(s => s.Id == uid);

        if (btnSubmit == "saveSellerPassword")
        {
            seller.Password = editSellerViewModel.ChangePasswordModel.NewPassword;
            bmDBCont.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(seller, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            bmDBCont.SaveChanges(); //<-- does nothing
        }

        if (TryUpdateModel(seller, "Seller")) //<-- never true
        {
            bmDBCont.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Titles = CommonListsProvider.GetTitles();
        ViewBag.Countries = CommonListsProvider.GetCountries();

        return View(editSellerViewModel);
    }
```

Here some debug info screenshots:

- [formcollection with seller form submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKINW.jpg)
- [formcollection with password form submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W59AR.jpg)

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: And what do you have in `ModelState` after TryUpdateModel? Do yuo have any errors?

Comment: A good hint - if i send the SellerData form, `ModelState` contains one field that has an error - "password". Of course, the password field was removed from the SellerData form because its in the Password form. I thought if a field is not set in the request, the binding would not try to update it?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation about TryUpdateModel, its says "Updates the specified model instance using values from the controller's current value provider and a prefix."

The Prefix to use when looking up values in the value provider.

Try use TryUpdateModel(seller) simple method without the "prefix" parameter.

```
if(TryUpdateModel(seller))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493137(v=vs.108).aspx